# grunt-mocha-test throwing errors that I expect to be caught in my try/catch block

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, try-catch, gruntjs, mocha.js

I am performing rest api validation using grunt-mocha-test (test written in coffeescript). The client i'm using to call the api will throw a custom defined error if the response is anything other than a 200. In some cases, such a response simply means the database isn't ready with the data that I am validating, so I want to poll the service until either it is ready or I timeout. Since an error is thrown each time it's not ready (i.e. not 200), I want to wrap my calls in a try/catch block -- retrying in the catch block. Unfortunately, mocha throws my error instead of allowing my catch block to catch it.

Below is an example of my code:

```
Client = require 'rest-client'
client = new Client

describe "Try catch test", ->
  it 'should catch my error', (done) ->
    retry = (done) ->  
      try
          client.mightThrowAnError, (response) ->
            done()
      catch error
        retry done

    retry done
```

Of course, in practice I have code in the catch block that eventually errors out after a number of retries so I don't recursively call retry forever, but I've omitted that here for simplicity, since mocha throws the error instead of ever allowing my catch block to handle it:

```
Uncaught Error: <my custom Error>
```

Is this a bug/design limitation with Mocha or am I doing something wrong?

[EDIT: The error thrown is a custom Error defined in my rest client]

Comment: What's the error you see? If you get a traceback it would be helpful to see it.

Comment: The error is the custom error defined in and thrown by my rest client. I'm expecting it to be thrown from that client and then caught in this test.

Comment: Are you getting a "Mocha exploded! SyntaxError"? Sounds like you're describing a different error though.

Comment: @making3 No, the error is my own. The mocha tests that follow all run as expected. It's just that my catch handler never gets the error -- mocha takes it and fails the test instead with the following error: "Uncaught Error: <my custom error>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a possibility. `client.mightThrowAnError` is doing something asynchronously. (Seems obvious.) If it is the *asynchronous* part of what `client.mightThrowAnError` which raises an error, this this will happen *outside* the `try...catch` block and will not be caught.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Looks like I might be able to use node's domain module to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.